# Possibility of having permanent DB when using Embedded Derby?

Tags: tomcat, derby

I am using the Embedded Derby version in my Web application (Eclipse, Tomcat, javax.ws.rs). When stopping the Tomcat Server,  currently, all databases will be deleted. Is there any way to store the databases permanently when using this embedded version? 
Moreover, I haven't found the location of the databases.

I am using the following library to shut down the database server:
https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/derby-shutdown-listener/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nailedtothex/derby/DerbyShutdownLifecycleListener.java

Thanks Matzka

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with embedded systems programming so I removed that tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is the JDBC Connection URL that you use in your application to connect to Derby? There are multiple possible explanations for the behavior you're seeing, but we need significantly more details to help you.

Comment: The reason was the specification of url="jdbc:derby:memory:mydb;create=true"/>. Skipping the memory tag, avoids the deletion of my data bases.